# Stream error handling

Tags: node.js, stream

I am using [got](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got) to stream a request. New to streams, I am not sure what the best way to deal with errors is. Specifically this request might send a 403, which I would like to catch, and not pipe the response if there is an error.

```
got.stream(url)
.on("error", (e) => {
    console.log(e)
})
.pipe(res)
```

In this example, the response will still get piped to `res` even if the response returned a `403`. What is the right way to keep the response from being piped, or is there a better or more idiomatic way to go about this?

Comment: were you using `got` inside your express middleware or node's http request handler?

Comment: @winter inside express middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with `url` pointing to my blog. However, it seems that it doesn't care whether the `error` event is triggered or not if you call `pipe` on `got` instance.

So, here's the workaround:

```
got.stream(url)
  .on('response', response => {
    response.pipe(res); // pipe to express's res.
  })
  .on('error', err => {
    // handle error
  });
```

Instead of calling the `pipe` directly from `got` object, you can listen for a response event to pipe the response you got to another response stream.

Comment: Thanks @winter! I was thinking I would have to workaround this some how, but I didn't think to only pipe the response in the `.on('response')` callback.